# .NET: What is the status of the Castle Project?

Tags: .net, castle

Clicking through to the download-page if see that the last version of the download is **over one year old** and it's also "just" a **Release Candidate** of version 1.0. There are really no news on any development.

Yes, you can find newer versions from the nightly builds, but that's not a real serious option.

Also, the "getting-started" and description-pages are sometimes not even started and some not completed.

What's the deal? Any C# 3.0 features on the way or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamilton Verissimo, the project founder, [took up a position with Microsoft](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=312) in August.

> **What happens to Castle?**
>
> That was a delicate subject to me, but surprisingly it wasn’t a problem to them. I got a written permission to keep working on Castle as much as I want. So nothing changes…
>
> **What happens to Castle Stronghold?**
>
> Albeit I was the frontman at CS, there’s a handful of talented people there. For the first time we were lucky hiring a junior developer - I couldn’t believe myself - and I’m positive the company will have a great future.
>
> I’m going to have a small share of the company, but wont be involved anymore. Stronghold also just had a share sold to one of our clients, I’ll release details soon once it gets signed.

Hammett has recently posted about [issues with .Net 3.5 SP1](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=321), so is evidently still working on it, but perhaps more from tightening things up from a MS end, than from pushing development on with Castle.

There are other developers still releasing daily builds etc, and the developer community is still very active on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel), if not also on the project homepage.

Comment: I would say the speculation that the team would lose focus without hammet giving it his full attention is probably wrong - also I actually think hammet has appeared _MORE_ active since joining MS - perhaps because his castle stronghold project load was very taxing/high?

Comment: That's a fair point - "loss of focus" was a poor turn of phrase on my part, talking mainly about the project webpage. Answer updated to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the "Release candidates" are misnamed.  "Milestones" might be better.  All areas of Castle are still under continuous development, and as far as I know, most users use the trunk version (I do).  And there are a number of very active developers working on it besides Hamilton.

There are two active Google Groups for it:

http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel (for development of Castle)

http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users (for users of Castle)

> Any C# 3.0 features on the way or
>   what?

It's completely compatible with .Net 3.5 right now.  There is currently a poll on the development newsgroup about dropping VS2005 (i.e. C#2) support and going fully C#3.  (I believe it's about 20:1 in favor) Some portions of the CastleContrib already are using C#3 features.

Comment: "C# 3.0 features" is not the same as "compatible with .NET 3.5". Every version of .NET and C# is "compatible with .NET 3.5".